# Replacing multiple strings using str_replace not working

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

**site_pages:**

`$site_pages = 'groups_permissions.php,b.php,c.php,d.php';`

**values to replace:**

```
$id = 'groups_permissions.php,b.php,c.php,d.php';
```

**expected result:**
`should be empty`

I am using the following to create array using the above comma separated list:

```
            // THIS WILL CREAET ARRAY LIKE 'groups_permissions.php','b.php','c.php','d.php'
            $egu_explode = explode(",", $id);
            $editgroup_users_array = "'" . implode ( "', '", $egu_explode ) . "'";

            // REPLACE FROM COLUMN
            $site_pages = $db_con->query("SELECT site_pages FROM settings LIMIT 1")->fetchColumn();
            $remove_page = str_replace([$editgroup_users_array], '', $site_pages);
            $remove_commas = preg_replace("/,+/", ",", $remove_page);
            $updated_pages = trim($remove_commas, ",");
echo $updated_pages;
```

**PROBLEM:**
The above code does not replace any string and gives values from `site_pages`column but if I place the `array('groups_permissions.php','b.php','c.php','d.php')` manually in `str_replace` then it replaces the strings perfectly.

Comment: What all does `$site_pages` contain?

Comment: What are you getting in `$site_pages`?

Comment: @vivek_23 it contains`groups_permissions.php,b.php,c.php,d.php

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$editgroup_users_array = "'" . implode ( "', '", $egu_explode ) . "'";
```

to

```
$editgroup_users_array = implode(",", $egu_explode);
```

AND

```
$remove_page = str_replace([$editgroup_users_array], '', $site_pages);
```

to

```
$remove_page = str_replace($editgroup_users_array, '', $site_pages);
```

**UPDATE #1**

Better to directly do,

```
$remove_page = str_replace($id,'', $site_pages);
```

**UPDATE #2**

If you want to replace `groups_permissions.php`,`b.php`,`c.php`,`d.php` regardless of their order, pass them in an array as shown below.

```
$remove_page = str_replace(array('groups_permissions.php','b.php','c.php','d.php'),'',$site_pages);
```

Or, in your case, you can better do like this-

```
$remove_page = str_replace($egu_explode,'',$site_pages);
```

Comment: thanks its working can you please elaborate about why i cant diirectly use that `$id` in str_replace instead of using implode?and what is implode doing? how str_replace is replacing the values without any sort of array because of multiple value?

Comment: @MR_AMDEV The issue in your code was you were putting single quotes `'`  in `implode` which weren't needed. So PHP read `groups_permissions.php,b.php,c.php,d.php` as `'groups_permissions.php','b.php','c.php','d.php'` instead.

Comment: isn't that required for using array(multiple strings) in `[ ]` or `array( )` in str_replace?

Comment: @MR_AMDEV `[$editgroup_users_array]` technically consists of a `single` element in the array having  `'groups_permissions.php','b.php','c.php','d.php'` whereas `array('groups_permissions.php','b.php','c.php','d.php')` has proper string at each location. Hence, the former one didn't work and the latter one worked.

Comment: hmmm Thanks I really didn't know about that!

Comment: it not working if values are `groups_permissions.php,d.php` or different in order from that of the `site_pages`  its giving the whole site_pages strings.

Comment: @MR_AMDEV Well, order does matter since we are passing a string. If you want to replace regardless of the order, then go with your `array('groups_permissions.php','b.php','c.php','d.php')` approach. That will work because it checks for each string. So, order won't matter here.

Comment: Can you please how can i do that regardless of the order? i was trying for that the rest of the time

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a variable like this `[$editgroup_users_array]` then it will consider it an array and it will give like the following output.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'groups_permissions.php', 'b.php', 'c.php', 'd.php'
)
```

and if you are using it as directly like this :

```
str_replace(['groups_permissions.php', 'b.php', 'c.php', 'd.php'],'',$site_pages);
```

It will work.

So, your `str_replace` function should not use `[]` as it will convert a string to an array.
So you should simply remove brackets `[]` and use this.

```
$remove_page = str_replace($editgroup_users_array, '', $site_pages);
```

**OR**

As [@vivek_23](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4964822/vivek-23) said, you should simply use this:

```
$remove_page = str_replace($id,'', $site_pages);
```

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explain.I appreciate it.